# Tag highlighting on main SO page

Tags: script, stackoverflow, tampermonkey

### Motivation

I recently added more than one "Favourite" tag and got pretty irritated by the sea of yellow on the home page.

As such I wrote this little user script (for use in Chrome's Tampermonkey) which grabs your favourite tags and colors them differently.

### Code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Multiple colors on StackOverflow home
// @namespace  http://davunderscorei.co.uk
// @version    0.2
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      *stackoverflow.com/*
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// @copyright  2014 dav_i
// ==/UserScript==

StackExchange.ready(function () {
    // set up styles
    var colors = ['#ffefc6', 
        'rgb(240, 171, 171)', 
        'rgb(200, 228, 164)',
        'rgb(171, 196, 240)'];
    
    var scriptTag = '<style type="text/css">';
    
    $.each(colors, function(i, x) {
        scriptTag += '.dav_i.tag-' + i + '{ background-color: ' + x + ' } ';
    });
    
    scriptTag += '</style>';
    
    $('head').append(scriptTag);
    
    var tags = $.map(
                $('#interestingTags').children('a'),
                function (x) {
                   return $(x).text().replace('#', 'ñ');
                });
       
    var interestingQuestionSelector = '.question-summary.tagged-interesting';
    var interestingQuestions = $(interestingQuestionSelector);
    
    $.each(tags, function(i, x) {
        interestingQuestions
            .find('.tags.t-' + x + ':not(.dav_i)')
            .parents(interestingQuestionSelector)
            .addClass('dav_i tag-' + (i % colors.length));    
    });
});
```

Thought I'd share it incase anyone else is as irritated by this as me.

### Example

With favourites [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)
[image: Example image]

### Change log

#### 0.1

Initial release

#### 0.2

Using classes instead of inline styles and only using first tag to style.

Comment: @Hemang Download Tampermonkey for Chrome and install in that.

Comment: @Hemang Yes it is.